# How can I produce high CPU load on a Linux server?

Tags: performance, debian, benchmarking

I’m currently in the process of [debugging a Cacti installation](https://serverfault.com/questions/403566/why-does-cacti-keep-waiting-for-dead-poller-processes/403736) and want to create CPU load to debug my CPU utilization graphs.

I tried to simply run `cat /dev/zero > /dev/null`, which works great but only utilizes 1 core:

[image]

Is there a better method of testing/maxing-out system resources under load?

> Related: [How can I produce high CPU load on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/396501/how-can-i-produce-highcpu-load-on-windows)

Comment: is it possible to run multiple instances of `cat` simultaneously?

Comment: @NateKoppenhaver: Yes, that seems to be possible when wrapping them in `screen` sessions. But I would prefer a more sophisticated solution if possible.

Comment: Heh, I always used `cat /dev/random > /dev/null`. Guess `/dev/zero` works too. :-)

Comment: @oKtosiTe cat /dev/random has the side effect of depleting the entropy in /dev/random. There are times you need to conserve entropy, I wouldn't have this as my go to CPU hog.

Comment: @oKtosiTe What Rich Homolka said is right, but it's not just that it's a bad thing to do, it's also useless because it'll block almost immediately and stop consuming cpu.

Comment: @Luc This isn't always true. With `haveged` you can create enough entropy.

Comment: @Stefan Interesting, I didn't know that tool existed. Still, it isn't installed by default on any Debian (based) distribution that I know of.

Comment: I've been using `matho-primes all >/dev/null &` but it's undoubtedly not the BEST answer for everyone.

Answer (score 303, accepted):

Try [`stress`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stress)
It's pretty much an equivalent of the Windows `consume.exe`:

```
oliver$ ./stress --cpu 3
stress: info: [18472] dispatching hogs: 3 cpu, 0 io, 0 vm, 0 hdd
```

Comment: on ubuntu, you can install with `sudo apt-get install stress`

Comment: on debian wheezy too.

Comment: On Fedora, `sudo yum install stress`

Comment: Arch: `sudo pacman -S stress`

Comment: `brew install stress` on OS X

Comment: From source: ```wget http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/stress-1.0.4.tar.gz && tar -xvf stress-1.0.4.tar.gz && cd stress-1.0.4 && ./configure && make && sudo make install``` 
See [README](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~apw/stress/README).

Comment: On Amazon Linux, `sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel -y && sudo yum install stress -y` ([ref](https://gist.github.com/mikepfeiffer/d27f5c478bef92e8aff4241154b77e54))

Comment: The link to the stress package is dead

Comment: This one worked on Amazon linux EC2 --- sudo yum install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm and then
sudo yum install stress -y

Comment: My choice is the other _one-line solution_ below which does not require any installation: https://superuser.com/a/443633/451797

Comment: stress-ng https://github.com/ColinIanKing/stress-ng

Answer (score 150):

No need to install any extra package, your good old shell is able to do it alone.

This one-liner will load your four cores<sup>1</sup> at 100%:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4; do while : ; do : ; done & done
```

How it works is quite simple, it starts four endless loops. Each of them is repeating the null instruction (`:`). Each loop is able to load a CPU core at 100%.

If you use `bash`, `ksh93` and other shells supporting ranges, (i.e. not `dash` or older `ksh`), you can use this non portable syntax:

```
for i in {1..4}; do ...
```

Replace `4` with the number of CPUs you'd like to load if different from `4`.

Assuming you had no background job already running when you launched one of these loops, you can stop the load generation with that command:

```
for i in 1 2 3 4; do kill %$i; done
```

---

Answering @underscore_d's comment, here is an enhanced version that simplify a lot stopping the load and that also allow specifying a timeout (default 60 seconds.) A <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> will kill all the runaway loops too. This shell function works at least under `bash` and `ksh`.

```
# Usage: lc [number_of_cpus_to_load [number_of_seconds] ]
lc() {
  (
    pids=""
    cpus=${1:-1}
    seconds=${2:-60}
    echo loading $cpus CPUs for $seconds seconds
    trap 'for p in $pids; do kill $p; done' 0
    for ((i=0;i<cpus;i++)); do while : ; do : ; done & pids="$pids $!"; done
    sleep $seconds
  )
}
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>Note that with CPUs supporting more than one thread per core (Hyper-threading), the OS will dispatch the load to all virtual CPUs. In that case, the load behavior is implementation dependent (each thread might be reported as 100% busy or not).</sub>.

Comment: Thanks, but `&` causes a command to run in a separate _thread_ or separate _core_? I am confused.

Comment: @mmdemirbas: The ampersand causes the command to run as a separate process. The scheduler is then dispatching all the active processes to all available cores .

Comment: As a reminder you can stop this test by issuing `killall bash` - just make sure you don't have any other important script running at the time.

Comment: @acoder Thanks for suggesting a way to end the loop. I would however avoid `killall bash`. Answer edited to add a safer method to end the load generation.

Comment: or simply end them with `fg` ctrl+c,  4 times.

Comment: +1 for the lc shell function

Comment: I used this in a script for testing!

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried 'for i in 1 2 3 4; do while : ; do : ; done & done'. My question is how to verify/check the CPU load accordingly? I used 'top', however, the % load per each thread is not 100%...Please advise.

Comment: @Amber.G You can run `htop` as the OP or `mpstat` to see per CPU load.

Comment: Succinctly, if no other BG jobs are running - `kill $(jobs -p)`

Comment: These all end up being run on the same core for me.

Comment: @cz On multiple threads sharing the same core or on a single thread/core? What OS, CPU and scheduler are you running?

Answer (score 53):

One alternative way would be

```
openssl speed -multi $(grep -ci processor /proc/cpuinfo)
```

or (if nproc is present)

```
openssl speed -multi $(nproc --all)
```

OpenSSL is almost always present on nowadays distros, so no extra packages needed.

Comment: imho this should be the accepted answer because it doesn't require any additional packages and it takes care of all cores.

Answer (score 24):

I made a simple python script which does the same. You can control the number of cpu cores you want to load. The good thing about this is that it won't consume any other resource besides the cpu. (I think mark johnson's idea would consume a lot of I/O resources, which is undesired here.)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    # Put any cpu (only) consuming operation here. I have given 1 below -
    while True:
        x * x

# decide how many cpus you need to load with.
no_of_cpu_to_be_consumed = 3

p = Pool(processes=no_of_cpu_to_be_consumed)
p.map(f, range(no_of_cpu_to_be_consumed))
```

Just run this script from the terminal `$ python temp1.py`. You need to kill the script when you are done.

Here, is my cpu consumption output when I load 3 of my cores.

[image: Script temp1.py creates three processes (PIDs - 9377, 9378, 9379) which load 3 of my cores]

Comment: What program do you used to display CPU usage like this? It reminds me of top, but I don't recall the CPU 'charts'.

Comment: @jftuga probably _htop_, _top_'s prettier brother.

Comment: yes its htop. Best real time, colorful interactive process viewer for linux - http://htop.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Wasn't paying attention and ran this on a Windows box. Very bad things...

Answer (score 20):

Start two

```
sha1sum /dev/zero &
```

commands for every core in your system.

To stop

```
killall sha1sum
```

or

```
kill sha1sum
```

Comment: Like this one. Short & sweet and didn't need to download anything.

Answer (score 11):

I've been developing stress-ng, an updated stress tool that can stress a wide range of aspects of a Linux system.  For more information, see http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~cking/stress-ng/

Usage is similar to [stress](https://superuser.com/a/443409/139234)

```
$ stress-ng --cpu 4 --vm 2 --fork 8 --switch 4 --timeout 1m
stress-ng: info:  [32254] dispatching hogs: 4 cpu, 8 fork, 4 switch, 2 vm
stress-ng: info:  [32254] cache allocate: default cache size: 8192K
```

Install with

```
sudo apt-get install stress-ng
```

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. At the very least you should provide more than just/at least a link, for example some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Answer (score 7):

I usually take the cpuburn suite:

```
sudo apt-get install cpuburn
for i in {1..4}; do burnK7 & done
```

Replace 4 with the number of cores / HT-threads you have or want to stress.

Note: This stresses as much chip area as possible at the same time, it's programmed to generate maximum power dissipation. I had to write this post a second time, somehow my machine didn't like it :-(

You could also do cpuburn in sequences:

```
burnP6 & burnP6 & burnP6 & burnP6 & 
[1] 28520
[2] 28521
[3] 28522
[4] 28523
```

And when you want to stop them:

```
killall burnP6
```

You could also multiply `burnP6 &` to match the number of CPU cores on your system.

Answer (score 3):

You can run that command as many times as you want, and it will take up a different core each time:

```
$ CORES=1
$ for i in `seq 1 $CORES`; do cat /dev/zero > /dev/null &
> done
[1] 8388
```

Comment: Wouldn't that make terminating the processes a bit of a hassle?

Comment: `killall cat` should do it.

Comment: Depending on whether you have other `cat` processes running (I usually do).

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/GaetanoCarlucci/CPULoadGenerator

pretty simple and scientific solution.

Here you can see dynamics example in which 50% load is generated on CPU core 0:

[image]

You can run the process on other cores at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I combined both +jlliagre and +ecabuk.

```
#!/bin/bash
lc() {
    nowMs=$(date +%s)
    (
        pids=""
        cpus=${1:-1}
        seconds=${2:-60}
        echo "[$(date)] loading $cpus CPUs for $seconds seconds"
        echo "[$(date)] Expected completion: [$(date --date=@$(expr $nowMs + $seconds))]"
        trap 'for p in $pids; do kill $p; done' 0
        for ((i=0;i<cpus;i++)); do
            sha1sum /dev/zero &
            pids="$pids $!";
        done
        sleep $seconds
    )
    echo "[$(date)] Done"
}

lc $@
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the way I use and there's no need to install anything extra.

For example to start with 4 processes,

```
nproc | xargs seq | xargs -n1 -P4 md5sum /dev/zero
```

You can change the number of processes by the option "-P" above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
fulload() { dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null | dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null & }; fulload; read; killall dd
```

Repeat `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null` for your CPU cores.

Hit any key to stop the test!

Answer (score 1):

`pxz` is a parallel implementation of `xz`.

`pxz -9e /dev/zero --stdout >/dev/null` should do the trick, as this is quite cpu intensive.

If `/dev/zero` is not fast enough (you notice that `pxz` gets I/O throttled) you can do
`pxz -9e /dev/zero --stdout | pxz -9e  --stdout >/dev/null`

Newer versions of `xz` have the `--threads` option which is a substitute for `pxz`.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add this to @jlliagre's comment, but I don't have enough reputation. If you're going to use this code on multiple servers and the CPU count will vary, you can use the following command:

```
for ((i=1; i<=`nproc --all`; i++)); do while : ; do : ; done & done
```

This will utilize all of the cores on your server regardless of how many you have. The command `nproc` is part of coreutils so should be on most Linux installations.

Answer (score 1):

Dockerized solution, using `stress`.
Can be deployed using k8s to cover multiple machines.

https://hub.docker.com/r/jfusterm/stress

Answer (score 0):

A simple command line does it too:

```
x="x" ; while : ; do x=$x$x ; echo -n "." ; done
```

Comment: This would be simpler: `while : ; do : ; done`

Comment: @jlliagre Yours wön't go above loadavg 1.

Comment: Your loop isn't primarily loading the CPU but more filling the memory. It will eventually crash with an out of memory error.

Comment: @jlliagre Mine fills memory and swap (if present), thus producing a load of 3 before it killed because it runs out of memory.

Comment: That's the problem. You aren't answering the question asked which is how to produce a high CPU load on a server. Your script is quickly making a system unresponsive and then crashes. There are much more reliable ways to get a loadavg of 3. eg: `for i in 1 2 3; do while : ; do : ; done & ; done`

Answer (score 0):

Run the program `stress` specifying all the cores you have on your CPU:

```
stress -c `nproc`
```

You can get it on Debian/Ubuntu:
`sudo apt install stress`